# How to convert to a LocalDateTime field in an @ParameterObject with @DateTimeFormat pattern instead of iso?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, springdoc

**Update: It's not even a question, it's completely my DUMB. Plz down vote this question.**

thanks to @M. Deinum points out that's not a spring thing.

my IDEA's settings messed up in a crash this morning and not auto-compile before re-running.

=========================

The Controller

```java
@GetMapping("/page")
public Response Page(@ParameterObject Page page, @ParameterObject QueryDTO param) {
    /*
     * irrelevant parts omitted
     */
}
```

When I use this in DTO, it works well with `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` pattern passed-in.

```java
@Data
public class QueryDTO {
    /*
     * irrelevant parts omitted
     */
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime startTime;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime endTime;
}
```

But when I want to use a ' ' instead of the 'T', I tried:

```java
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

and change the input param from "1999-02-11T00:00:00" to "1999-02-11 00:00:00", I got

`endTime Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime' for property 'endTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime] for value [1999-02-11 00:00:00]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [1999-02-11 00:00:00]`

Is there any solution to use an annotation rather than writing a converter manually?

Many thanks.

I tried google with keywords "LocalDateTime @ParameterObject @DateTimeFormat pattern", not getting much help.

Comment: Can you share the input and describe what *It does not work.* means?

Comment: @Jens I add some information of the error.

Comment: What is `@ParameterObject`? That isn't a Spring annotaiton.

Comment: @M.Deinum It's a springdoc-openapi annotation, from springdoc-openapi-common-1.6.15.jar

Comment: Try with `yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss` as a pattern, although it might not be used for binding and only for printing (it is a formatter in that regard). Please add the full stacktrace as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum Really thank you to point out that's not a spring thing. I'm feeling like I'm to stupid to learn programming.

Comment: I was just wondering if you implemented something yourself, which is possible and could break things with Spring. This annotation won't as it is just used for metadata generation. So it was more to rule some things out then to point fingers, just needed the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The `@DateTimeFormat` annotation is typically used for formatting and parsing date-time values when binding request parameters in `Spring MVC` controllers. However, it does not support custom patterns with spacs directly.

**To achieve specified pattern, you can use the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation with the pattern and also aply the `@InitBinder`.**

```
@GetMapping("/page")
public Response page(@ParameterObject Page page, @ParameterObject QueryDTO param) {
    // Your code
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class DateTimeFormatConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        binder.addCustomFormatter(new LocalDateTimeFormatter(formatter));
    }

    private static class LocalDateTimeFormatter implements Formatter<LocalDateTime> {

        private final DateTimeFormatter formatter;

        public LocalDateTimeFormatter(DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
            this.formatter = formatter;
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDateTime parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
        }

        @Override
        public String print(LocalDateTime object, Locale locale) {
            return formatter.format(object);
        }
    }
}
```

- By applying this configuartion, you should be able to use the pattern **"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"** with the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation in your **QueryDTO class**.

**If you want to apply a pattern directly in the annotation without a global configuration, you can use a different method:**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
public @interface CustomDateTimeFormat {
}

public class QueryDTO {
    // Your code

    @CustomDateTimeFormat
    private LocalDateTime startTime;

    @CustomDateTimeFormat
    private LocalDateTime endTime;

    // Getters and setters
}

@Controller
public class YourController {

    @GetMapping("/page")
    public Response page(@ParameterObject Page page, @ParameterObject QueryDTO param) {
        // Your code
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addCustomFormatter(new LocalDateTimeFormatter());
    }

    private static class LocalDateTimeFormatter implements Converter<String, LocalDateTime> {

        @Override
        public LocalDateTime convert(String source) {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            return LocalDateTime.parse(source, formatter);
        }
    }
}
```

- I've added a custom annotation that encapsulates the desired pattern and use it in your **`QueryDTO` class**. Then, you can write a custom `Converter` **to convert the annotated string** to a **`LocalDateTime` object** using the **specified pattern**.

Please let me know if it soled your problem, and if so, then please **leave your opinions**. ^^

Comment: Thank you for answering, I'm going to have a try.

Comment: This will apply it globally, it shoudl work with a pattern as well on the annotation.